# Get group counts of level 1 after doing a group by on two columns

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I am doing a group by on two columns and need the count of the number of values in level-1

I tried the following:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['one', 'one', 'two', 'three', 'three', 'one'], 'B': [1, 2, 0, 4, 3, 4], 'C': [3,3,3,3,4,8]})
>>> print(df)
       A  B  C
0    one  1  3
1    one  2  3
2    two  0  3
3  three  4  3
4  three  3  4
5    one  4  8
>>> aggregator = {'C': {'sC' : 'sum','cC':'count'}}
>>> df.groupby(["A", "B"]).agg(aggregator)
/envs/pandas/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby/generic.py:1315: FutureWarning: using a dict with renaming is deprecated and will be removed in a future version
  return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
         C   
        sC cC
A     B      
one   1  3  1
      2  3  1
      4  8  1
three 3  4  1
      4  3  1
two   0  3  1
```

I want an output something like this where the last column `tC` gives me the count corresponding to group `one`, `two` and `three`.

```py
         C   
        sC cC tC
A     B      
one   1  3  1 3
      2  3  1
      4  8  1
three 3  4  1 2
      4  3  1
two   0  3  1 1
```

Comment: Where does "tc" come from?!

Comment: tC is what I need. That is the count of group by column "A". cC is the count of group by ["A","B"]. Is there a way to get both these counts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one column for aggregation pass list of tuples:

```
aggregator = [('sC' , 'sum'),('cC', 'count')]
df = df.groupby(["A", "B"])['C'].agg(aggregator)
```

For last column convert first level to `Series` of `MultiIndex`, get counts by [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) and [`GroupBy.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.size.html) and for first values only use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
s = df.index.get_level_values(0).to_series()
df['tC'] = np.where(s.duplicated(), np.nan, s.groupby(s).transform('size'))
print(df)
         sC  cC   tC
A     B             
one   1   3   1  3.0
      2   3   1  NaN
      4   8   1  NaN
three 3   4   1  2.0
      4   3   1  NaN
two   0   3   1  1.0
```

You can also set duplicated values to empty string in `tC` column, but then later all numeric operation  with this column failed, because mixed values - numeric with strings:

```
df['tC'] = np.where(s.duplicated(), '', s.groupby(s).transform('size'))
print(df)
         sC  cC tC
A     B           
one   1   3   1  3
      2   3   1   
      4   8   1   
three 3   4   1  2
      4   3   1   
two   0   3   1  1
```